# Подключение к microsoft teams api с помощью c#

Tags: c#, api

Не могу сообразить, где брать id для работы с microsoft teams api. Мне нужно зарегестрировать мое приложение в сервисах microsoft? Или он должен быть где в приложении microsoft teams?

```
            string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(id) // тут я должен передать Microsoft App Id
                .Build();

            var authenticationProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
            User me = graphClient.Me.Request()
                                .GetAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала стоит посмотреть в [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#client-id) `PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create()`.

> Идентификатор клиента — это уникальный идентификатор приложения (клиента), назначенный приложению службой Azure AD при регистрации приложения.

Далее логично поискать, где написано про то, как это сделать. Иду в поиск `azure ad зарегистрировать приложение` и нахожу:

- [Руководство по регистрации веб-приложения в Azure Active Directory B2C](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga)
- [Краткое руководство. Регистрация приложения с помощью платформы удостоверений Майкрософт](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app)

Чтение документации от Microsoft с пониманием, что там вообще написано, иногда задача не простая. Но в вашем случае это самый короткий путь к решению.

Comment: Большое спасибо